# Change git hook credentials in Windows

Tags: python, windows, git, clearcase

I am running in Windows and have a git post-receive hook that calls a python 3 script. This Python script does a number of things. One of these is to output the username running the git hook. This username is MACHINENAME$ (where the machine name is MACHINENAME), which I think is the Network Service account, but I could be wrong here. After that it calls subprocess.run which execs a call to the ClearCase command clearfsimport. Note that I use the clearfsimport 'nsetevent' switch which does allow other users to check-in to this view, but this doesn't seem to work for the Network Service account.

If I run the python command directly as the ClearCase view owner, the clearfsimport succeeds. If I run it as another user, the clearfsimport succeeds. If I run it as a git hook, however, it fails with the following error message:

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['clearfsimport', '-recurse', '-nsetevent', '-rmname', '-comment', "This is my comment", '/path/to/clearfsimport/source', '/path/to/ClearCase/view']' returned non-zero exit status 1

What can I do to get this git hook to work correctly? It does not matter if I have to adjust python, git, ClearCase, or Windows, or some combination.

Answer (score 0):

Since a git hook executes itself in a git bash, check if that affect how the parameters are passed to the windows executable `clearfsimport` (especially the path)

One simple test: wrap your `clearfsimport` call in a `.bat` script, and set the source and destination path in that script, then make your git hook call said script.